# PostgreSQL SELECT query stack?

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql

I'm using Java, Postgres and I'm trying to select some data from the database using a select query and set the result on the table. But I get an empty table! Even if chosen value is on the database

here is the code :

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Rechercher");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                Connection conn = conectar();  
                String b = "Ordre";
                String a = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println("ordre = " + a);

                if(a == b) {  

                    String sql2 = "select * from ordre where num_ordre = '" +textArea.getText()+"'";
                    Statement stm2;

                     try {

                        stm2  = conn.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs1 = stm2.executeQuery(sql2);
                         while (rs1.next()) {

                             table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs1));

                         }
                         rs1.close();
                         stm2.close();
                     }

                     catch(SQLException e2 ) {

                         System.out.println("Error = " + e2.getMessage());

                     }
                }

                else {

                    System.out.println("LA CONDITION N EST PAS SATISFAITE");
                }

            }
```

Comment: Have you made sure that textArea.getText() contains what you're expecting?  Is num_ordre a varchar column?  Also, string comparison with `==` is a no no in Java.  Use `if (a.equals(b))` instead.

Comment: Do not concatenate strings from a user input into a SQL statement. Use a `PreparedStatement` instead.

Comment: About if condition i'am sure it dosn't stack here, or it will automaticaly move to the "else" ! and even if i remove the if condition i get an empty table, so i think the problem comes from sql query, i'll try the Preparestatement and answer you thank you a lot for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `==` operator to compare `String`s in Java - it checks that both objects are the same **reference**, not that their content is equal. Instead, you should use the `equals(Object)` method:

```
if (a.equals(b)) { // Instead of using ==
```